# Playwright tests fail when using pages as fixtures

Tags: typescript, playwright, webautomation

I would need some help with this tests and the approach that I am testing.
I use run all the tests in the spec file one after another.

1. When I call the pages in the tests and I run the spec file, all the tests run in the same context and in the same page.
2. When I use the pages as fixtures, after the first test is done I get `browserContext.close` and the context closes after the first test, so the second test fails.

Anything that is different between the 2 tests is that in the 1st I call the pages in the tests (default POM) and in the 2nd I call the pages as fixtures. I have basePage fixture where I make fixture for every page.

The first spec where I call the pages in the tests. This is working fine and all tests pass:

```
test.describe.configure({ mode: 'serial' });
let page: Page;

test.beforeAll(async ({ browser }) => {
    page = await browser.newPage();
});

test.afterAll(async () => {
    await page.close();
});

test('Signup', async () => {
    const registration = new signupPage(page);
    await registration.goToSignupUrl();
    await registration.enterEmail(loginData.adminEmail);
    await registration.enterPassword(loginData.password);
    await registration.clickSignupButton();
    await expect(page).toHaveURL(/.*home/);
});

test('Simulate form submission', async ({ request }) => {
    const userID = await getUserID(page);
    await simulateFormSubmission(request, userID);
    await page.reload();
});

test('Add user info', async () => {
    const addInfo = new addInfoPage(page);
    await addInfo.clickAddInfoButton();
    await addInfo.enterName(userData.name);
    await addInfo.enterNumber(userData.number);
    await addInfo.enterBirthdate(userData.birthdate);
    await addInfo.clickAddUserInfo();
});
```

Then I create basePage fixture for the pages.

```
type pages = {
    registration: signupPage;
    addInfo: addInfoPage;
}

export const test = basePage.extend<pages>({
    registration: async ({ page }, use) => {
        await use(new signupPage(page))
    },

    addInfo: async ({ page }, use) => {
        await use(new addInfoPage(page))
    }
})
```

And this is the second test where I use the pages as fixtures and the second test from the spec file fails with error `browserContext.close`

```
test.describe.configure({ mode: 'serial' });
let page: Page;

test.beforeAll(async ({ browser }) => {
    page = await browser.newPage();
});

test.afterAll(async () => {
    await page.close();
});

test('Signup', async ({ registration }) => {
    await registration.goToSignupUrl();
    await registration.enterEmail(loginData.adminEmail);
    await registration.enterPassword(loginData.password);
    await registration.clickSignupButton();
    await expect(page).toHaveURL(/.*home/);
});

test('Simulate form submission', async ({ request }) => {
    const userID = await getUserID(page);
    await simulateFormSubmission(request, userID);
    await page.reload();
});

test('Add user info', async ({ addInfo }) => {
    await addInfo.clickAddInfoButton();
    await addInfo.enterName(userData.name);
    await addInfo.enterNumber(userData.number);
    await addInfo.enterBirthdate(userData.birthdate);
    await addInfo.clickAddUserInfo();
});
```

I tried removing the hooks and also tried passing the page in the tests as parameter. One more thing that I noticed is that when I use the beforeAll hook in the second spec file where I use the pages as fixtures, when I run the test 2 browser contexts open. When I remove the beforeAll hook, only one context opens that runs the first test from the spec file. I am not sure how to make the spec file run all the tests in the same context and page, and not closing them after each test.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reproduce your issue and then made it work without the hooks.

You definitely do not need to use hooks for your setup with fixtures.

Assuming your page object allows access to the `page` object it got in it's constructor, the following will work:

Fixture

```
import { test as base } from '@playwright/test';
## imports to your page objects

type pages = {
    registration: signupPage;
    addInfo: addInfoPage;
}

export const test = basePage.extend<pages>({
    registration: async ({ page }, use) => {
        await use(new signupPage(page))
    },

    addInfo: async ({ page }, use) => {
        await use(new addInfoPage(page))
    }
})
export { expect, BrowserContext } from '@playwright/test';
```

Perhaps you were missing the `export` from fixture?

Tests

```
test.describe.configure({ mode: 'serial' });

test('Signup', async ({ registration }) => {
    await registration.goToSignupUrl();
    await registration.enterEmail(loginData.adminEmail);
    await registration.enterPassword(loginData.password);
    await registration.clickSignupButton();
    await expect(registration.page).toHaveURL(/.*home/);
});

test('Simulate form submission', async ({ page, request }) => {
    const userID = await getUserID(page);
    await simulateFormSubmission(request, userID);
    await page.reload();
});

test('Add user info', async ({ addInfo }) => {
    await addInfo.clickAddInfoButton();
    await addInfo.enterName(userData.name);
    await addInfo.enterNumber(userData.number);
    await addInfo.enterBirthdate(userData.birthdate);
    await addInfo.clickAddUserInfo();
});
```